# pandas drop where two columns match nested list values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I need to drop if any of the combinations in my nested list are met. 
Here's the sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','Green',10],['A','Red',20],['B','Blue',5],['B','Red',15],['C','Orange',25]],columns = ['Letter','Color','Value'])

print df

  Letter   Color  Value
0      A   Green     10
1      A     Red     20
2      B    Blue      5
3      B     Red     15
4      C  Orange     25
```

I have a list of letter/color combinations that I need to remove from the dataframe:

```
dropList = [['A','Green'],['B','Red']]
```

**How can I drop from the dataframe where the letter/color combinations are in any of the nested lists?** 
Approaches I can do if necessary, but want to avoid:

Write a .apply function

Any form of brute force iteration

Convert the dropList to a df and merge

```
#df_out = code here to drop if letter/color combo appears in my droplist
print df_out

  Letter   Color  Value
0      A     Red     20
1      B    Blue      5
2      C  Orange     25
```

I imagine there is some simple one/two line solution that I just can't see...Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a helper DF:

```
In [36]: drp = pd.DataFrame(dropList, columns=['Letter','Color'])
```

merge (left) your main DF with the helper DF and select only those rows that are missing in the right DF:

```
In [37]: df.merge(drp, how='left', indicator=True) \
           .query("_merge=='left_only'") \
           .drop('_merge',1)
Out[37]:
  Letter   Color  Value
1      A     Red     20
2      B    Blue      5
4      C  Orange     25
```

Comment: Ha, I had that as item 3 in the no-no list above (convert the dropList to a df and merge), but I guess if that's the best way I'll go with it. Was thinking there might be some index/unpacking list magic that wouldn't require the merge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the diff between the Letter Color combo and dropList to reindex the DF.

```
result = (
    df.set_index(['Letter','Color'])
    .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(x.index.difference(dropList)))
    .reset_index()
    )

result
Out[45]: 
  Letter   Color  Value
0      A     Red     20
1      B    Blue      5
2      C  Orange     25
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crazy use of isin() though my first choice would be @MaxU's solution

```
new_df = df[~df[['Letter', 'Color']].apply(','.join,axis = 1).isin([s[0]+','+s[1] for s in dropList])]

    Letter  Color   Value
1   A       Red     20
2   B       Blue    5
4   C       Orange  25
```

Comment: Yeah. That's award winning obfuscation code. Impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-indexing on the columns you use in `dropList` should do what you're after. Subtract the elements to be dropped from the full set of multiindex elements, then slice the dataframe by that remainder.

Note that the elements of `dropList` need to be tuples for the lookup.

```
dropSet = {tuple(elem) for elem in dropList}

# Creates a multi-index on letter/colour.
temp = df.set_index(['Letter', 'Color'])
# Keep all elements of the index except those in droplist.
temp = temp.loc[list(set(temp.index) - dropSet)]
# Reset index to get the original column layout.
df_dropped = temp.reset_index()
```

This returns:

```
In [4]: df_dropped
Out[4]: 
  Letter   Color  Value
0      B    Blue      5
1      A     Red     20
2      C  Orange     25
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is inspired by [@Wen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532006/9209546) to a later problem, please upvote there.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dropList, columns=['Letter', 'Color'])
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.merge(df2.assign(a='key'), how='left').dropna().index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the list of lists into a dictionary

```
mapper = dict(dropList)
```

Now filter out, by mapping the dictionary to the dataframe

```
df[df.Letter.map(mapper) != df.Color]
```

Yields

```
 Letter   Color  Value
1      A     Red     20
2      B    Blue      5
4      C  Orange     25
```